# zendesk interfering with e2e test with nightwatch

Tags: nightwatch.js, e2e-testing, zendesk

I have been having issues with my Zendesk covering up some of the buttons while testing e2e. I cannot disable my Zendesk for each test case, because they are are the highest level.

Is there a way to set the browser size on Nightwatch to be bigger than my computer screen size?

I have `args: ['window-size=4500,1170'],` but it seems like the window for chorme will not get any larger than my own screen size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the Zendesk widget hidden using the follow browser.execute() code.

```
browser.execute(function(){
   const zenDeskWidget = document.querySelector('#contact-widget-launcher');
   zenDeskWidget.style.display = "none"
},[]);
```

You may need to tweak your locator and the property to modify in order to hide it.The page I derived the widget I used for my example is https://www.zendesk.com/. If for some reason you want to write an acceptance test with the Zendesk widget just don't hide it (it's tough with the nested iFrames, I would just test the api).

Comment: Thanks, the zendesk and google analytics are slowing down the app. We ended up just disabling it completely from the dev env. If not, we had to execute extreme long waits to have CI working.

Comment: Good call Zendesk widgets definitely do test automation no favors.